# Getting wrong text sequence when image scanned by offline google mobile vision API

Tags: java, android, api

```
 public StringBuilder scanImage(Bitmap bp)
    {
        StringBuilder sb=null;
        TextRecognizer tcx = new 
        TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
        if (!tcx.isOperational())
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "could not get text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else
        {
            Frame fame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bp).build();
            SparseArray<TextBlock> items = tcx.detect(fame);
             sb = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i)
            {
                TextBlock mytext = items.valueAt(i);
                sb.append(mytext.getValue());
                sb.append("\n");

            }


        }
            return sb;

    }
```

this is my code. I'm using mobile google vision API. I'm just passing image bitmap  for scan but this method returns scanned text in wrong sequence.please tell me how to get text in proper sequence. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The detected blocks are not provided in sequence. You will need to check the position of each text block and do some maths to arrange them.

Use the methods such as `myText.getBoundingBox()`, `myText.getCornerPoints()`, etc to find the position of the text blocks.